# ASP.NET MVC multiple forms, staying on same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have forms located in multiple areas in my layout page (not nested).

I have a partial view which performs a post to controller action.

What action result do I return in that post to keep the user on the current page?

Is jquery/ajax my only option? I would rather a solution that didn't depend on javascript, maybe even a solution that degrades nicely.

Comment: iframes perhaps - i'd go with ajax though. Javascript is pretty web standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Request.Referrer` property to see what page the user has come from and then just use that to redirect them back there.

This does introduce other issues, e.g. losing `ModelState`, so you'll have to design for that. Also note that some users can block sending referrer information in their requests to the server - so the `Referrer` property can be null.

I would recommend using AJAX and then falling back on this.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do a RedirectToAction("") back to your main view.

Comment: But the current page (action) is unknown. This form exists in the layout page.

Answer (score 1):

To post a form without submitting the whole page, which refreshes the browser, you need to use Ajax/jQuery. The degraded solution is to submit the whole page like you would with a normal form.

Here's how I do it with jQuery.

Html:

```
<div id="RequestButtonDiv">
    <button id="RequestButton" name="Request" type="button">Request</button> 
</div>
```

This calls AddToCart on my Request controller when the RequestButton button is clicked. The response is placed inside the RequestButtonDiv element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#RequestButton').click(function (event) {
                    $('#RequestButton').text('Processing...');
                    $('#RequestButton').attr('disabled', true);
                    submitRequest();
                });
            });

            function submitRequest() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%: Url.Action("AddToCart", "Request", new { id = Model.RowId,  randomId = new Random().Next(1, 999999) }  ) %>',
                    success: function (response) {
                        // update status element
                        $('#RequestButtonDiv').html(response);
                    }
                });
            }           
 </script>
```

Controller action:

```
    public ActionResult AddToCart(int id)
    {
        var user = AccountController.GetUserFromSession();
        user.RequestCart.AddAsset(id);

        return View("~/Views/Assets/Details_AddToCart.ascx"); 
    }
```

The controller returns a partial view. You could also return Content("some stuff") instead.

Holler if you have questions or need more detail.